# How to popup and dismiss a view in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, addsubview

I have created **`.xib`** files and connected them with appropriate view controllers. Unfortunately, it doesn't go well.
I have checked and tried so many examples, but not working for newest version. Using **Xcode 11.3** and **iOS 13**. 
here is the code I have tried.
**TopView.swift**

```
@IBAction func btnConnectTapped(_ sender: Any) {        
        print("tapped")
        var listVC: PopupView    // This one is UIView and popped the window
        listVC = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("PopupView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! PopupView
        self.view.addSubview(listVC)

        // Tried for the UIViewController and not worked
        /*let VC = ScanViewController(nibName: "ScanViewController", bundle: nil)
        //self.present(VC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC, animated: true)*/
}
```

**Popup.swift** // dismiss the popped view

```
@IBAction func btnCancelTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.removeFromSuperview()
        }
}
```

both ScanViewController and Popup view have same purpose. 
Can someone help me

Comment: What exact problems do you have? You are not setting any constraints for your popup view.

Comment: @Sulthan it gives run time error when I tapped the button to remove the popup view.

Comment: you can use PopupDialog pod to show popups

Comment: @SiddhantNigam can you give an example?

Comment: How is `btnCancelTapped` connected in the xib? Is it connected to the view itself or to the owner?

Answer (score 0):

pod Url: https://github.com/Orderella/PopupDialog

eg to make Popup:

```
let ratingVC = TimeSelection(nibName: "TimeSelection", bundle: nil)
    ratingVC.view.backgroundColor = .white
    ratingVC.delegate = self
    let popup = PopupDialog(viewController: ratingVC,
                            buttonAlignment: .horizontal,
                            transitionStyle: .bounceDown,
                            tapGestureDismissal: true,
                            panGestureDismissal: true)
    popup.popupContainerView.backgroundColor = .clear
    present(popup, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score -1):

TopView.swift

```
@IBAction func btnTap(_ sender: UIButton)
   {
    if PopupScreensharedInstance != nil
    {
        PopupScreensharedInstance.makeInstanceNil()
    }
    view.addSubview(popView.SharedInstance())

}
```

popView.swift

```
var PopupScreensharedInstance : popView! = nil

class popView: UIView {
    class func SharedInstance() ->popView
    {
        if(PopupScreensharedInstance == nil)
        {
            PopupScreensharedInstance = (Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("popView", owner: self, options: nil)![0] as! popView)
            PopupScreensharedInstance.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        }
        return PopupScreensharedInstance
    }

    func makeInstanceNil()
    {
        PopupScreensharedInstance = nil
        self.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    @IBAction func cancle(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        makeInstanceNil()

    }
}
```